# Array prints well the objects values but triying to access to a value its prints Undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Im triying to access to the board_id of my objects on columnsServer array...

```
   columnsServer: Column[];

    this.service.getColumns()
    .subscribe(data => {
      this.columnsServer = data;
      console.log(this.columnsServer);
      for ( this.i = 0; this.i < this.columnsServer.length; this.i++) {
        console.log(this.columnsServer[this.i].board_id);
    }
  }
```

on the first console.log it prints all my properties well, but when im triying to acces to the board_id value its says undefined
[image: consoleScreenshot]

What im i doing wrong? i can acces to the other properties of the object, just the board_id is not working.

Thank you!

Comment: I don't see a `board_id` in your console.log screenshot. Did you mean to do `.board.id`?

Comment: I only see an `id` property, nothing called `board_id`.

Comment: I dont know why its says board, my column model is: `export class Column {
    constructor(public id: number, public name: string, public board_id: Board, public tasks: Task[]) {}
}`

Comment: this is a typio . There is no board_id. use board.id

Comment: Ohh i see, but then i dont know why the objects have that property board inside.

Comment: Because when you look at network tag in developer console. you get data from server like that. then u assign it to your object. You need to map data to your object rather than assign directly

Comment: Thank you all! i fixed it renaming board_id to board. As you say the problem comes from the server with other propertie name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't declare i inside component and actually no need of it. use your loop like below. Also you were accessing board_id actually it was board.id :-

```
for ( let i = 0; i < this.columnsServer.length; i++) {
  console.log(this.columnsServer[i].board.id);
}
```

Comment: Yes, I have my "i" number variable in the class, i forgot to declare it on the example, sorry

Comment: then change board_id to board.id

Comment: No, the propertie is named board_id `export class Column {
    constructor(public id: number, public name: string, public board_id: Board, public tasks: Task[]) {}
} ` Thank you anyways!

Comment: the json you printed don't have a property board_id

Comment: @Raúl Your `this.service.getColumns()` is returning the wrong format